# Manual Entry Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, dropdown

I have a list with a choice column with the option "Can add values manually" activated.

However, I wish that at the end of the month I would be able to clean the dropdown to prevent it from being polluted with too much information. But I would like to keep the entries in the list intact.

Is there any way I can do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Manually added values ​​will not be included in the drop-down list, if you uncheck the "Can add values ​​manually" option, the previous values ​still exist in list items.

Comment: I tried that option, but it didn't solve my problem :( When I recheck the "add values manually" option, the custom values return to the dropdown: S

Comment: I have also observed this behavior, manual values also show up in dropdown.

Comment: It would be interesting to be able to clear the Dropdown values, because by the end of the month I would have almost 50 items added. Users will end up wasting a lot of time looking for a single value. But I have no idea how to solve this: S

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, I edit it via Quick edit and Manually added values will not be included in the drop-down list, if I edit or add a new item, the manually  added values will be included in the drop-down list.

If you uncheck the “Can add values manually” in column settings, existing manually added values will not disappear, and it will no longer fill in the drop down list.